# User infomation in Loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm making a games backend in loopback. 
I have a user model defined as such.

```
{
  "name": "player",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "stats": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "stats",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

And I have the user stats defined as such:

```
{
  "name": "stats",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "experience": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true,
      "default": 0
    },
    "coins": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true,
      "default": 0
    },
    "titles": {
      "type": [
        "string"
      ],
      "required": true,
      "default": []
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

I want to eventually use the ALCs to so the user then cannot modify their own stats. But at the moment I cant work out how to automatically create the states when a user is registered. My first attempt was to generate the stats by using operation hooks so my player.js file is:

```
module.exports = function (Player) {
    var app = require('../../server/server');
    Player.observe('after save', function filterProperties(ctx, next) {
        var Stats = app.models.Stats;
        if(ctx.isNewInstance) {
            Stats.create({"playerId": ctx.instance.id});
        }
        next();
    });
};
```

But in my database nothing is showing up, does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do is add a proper callback to the `Stats.create()` method to see why the create method isn't doing what you expect, along with some more logic to send `next()` depending on the result of the operations. I also changed how you get a reference to the Stats model by accessing it through the Player model.

```
module.exports = function (Player) {

  Player.observe('after save', function filterProperties(ctx, next) {

    var Stats = Player.app.models.Stats;

    if(ctx.isNewInstance) {

      Stats.create({"playerId": ctx.instance.id}, function(err, stats) {

        if(err) {
          console.log("[Player after save] error creating stats instance for playerId " + ctx.instance.id, err);
          next(err);
        } else {
          console.log("[Player after save] Created new empty stats instance for playerId " + ctx.instance.id, stats);
          next();
        }

      });

    } else {
      console.log("[Player after save] Existing player instance, did not create stats");
      next();

    }

  });

};
```